# Redirect URL in java

Tags: java, post, resteasy, http-redirect

Hi I'm using Resteasy api for my webservice..
I have a resource that will accept a form post request..

```
@POST
@Path("/path_here")
public Response redirectURL(String req){
  String url = "http://localhost:8080/url_here";
  URL newUrl = new URL(url);
  return Response.temporaryRedirect(newUrl.toURI()).build();
}
```

the code above just post the requested parameters on the redirected URL..
so meaning the redirected URL has the post request params..

I would like to ask if there is a way to filter and change the request parameters before it goes to the redirect URL?

Comment: Clarify *edit the post request value*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all though you send request 'POST' to webservice, but your redirect URL will converted as 'GET' while redirecting to other site. I hope you already know this.

IF your end point is Servlet you can define one Filter before reaching to Servlet and try to edit the parameters.

Comment: yes I already knew that it is converted to GET.. How can I define this filter? sorry but i dont really have an idea :(

Answer (score 0):

The important concept of redirection is, server does not do the redirection. Server tells client "please go to this url" and client makes a GET request to the returned url automatically. What you can do is, taking the body from POST request, converting data from the body to url parameters, and change the url parameters as you wish.

P.S.: This is a way to solve your problem, it doesn't mean you should do it. Please don't do it and find another solution according to your context.